# Django admin panel django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-2.0

I am using django version 2.0 getting integrity error while trying to add  model element from admin panel.
Although i can add element from shell.

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Book)
```

i am using sqlite database

Got following error when add from admin panel

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/accounts/book/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 574, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1553, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1450, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: There's no foreign key in this model. Have you changed the model without running migrations?

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes in this model.
also I create a new model with char field got same error from admin panel.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same issue. The reason for the error is that django_admin_log has a foreign key to all the project's models so that it can log all changes made through the admin interface. Somehow, something in this connection is missing.

Comment: @brno32,  yes It was a migration error, delete all the migrations files and generate it again.